# Background task for Django on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, background-task

I have a problem I haven't been able to find a (simple) solution for.

In `views.py` at the moment

```py
from .utils import some_heavy_function

@login_required
def my_function_view(request):
    user = request.user
    instance = MyModel(user=user)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyModel_form(request.POST,instance = instance)    

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save(commit=False)
            
            #Run function which saves the form
            some_heavy_function(form)


            messages.success(request, "Success!")
            return redirect("my_template")
    else:
        form = MyModel_form()

    return render(request, "my_app/my_html.html")
```

As you can see, I want to run `some_heavy_function` in the background when the user submits a form - all it does is to run a python-script and update some values in `form.instance` based on the script. The user should not wait for this to end.

I have looked into `django-background-tasks`, `django-q` and  the `sync_to_async` but I have not managed to make it work (`sync_to_async` does not work with `@login_required`, `redis` does not work on windows and `django-background-tasks` needs an extra call to actually execute the queued processes)

What would be the best way to do so? My Django app is running on Google App Engine, if that makes it more easy

Comment: Check out Google Cloud Tasks.

Comment: Turned out, `threading` did the job beautifully